# Get unique occurrences of values from mysql database in date order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a raspberry pi project that sends switch state values to a mysql database every couple of minutes. Each switch value is either a 0, 1 or 2. The data in my database looks like this

```
Date                        value
2019-09-18 11:54:10         0
2019-09-18 11:52:58         0
2019-09-18 11:48:39         0
2019-09-18 11:24:28         1
2019-09-18 11:23:05         1
2019-09-17 13:01:25         1
2019-09-17 12:57:56         0
2019-08-29 15:32:43         0
2019-08-29 15:29:59         2
2019-03-20 11:42:09         2
2019-03-20 11:37:32         1
2019-01-25 11:05:18         0
```

I want the output to ignore the rows where the value is the same as the previous so the output will only be when the values change ie

```
Date                        value
2019-09-18 11:54:10         0
2019-09-18 11:24:28         1
2019-09-17 12:57:56         0
2019-08-29 15:29:59         2
2019-03-20 11:37:32         1
2019-01-25 11:05:18         0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I would go about this?

Comment: You say _the same as the previous_.  How is the order determined?  By the `Date` or do you have an `ID` field you use to order the results?

Comment: Yes it will be ordered by date, so that I can output a timeline of the date and time when the switch state changes

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The version of MYSQL I'm using is 5.7.26

Comment: Why isn't 2019-01-25 11:05:18         0 in your desired output?

Comment: Sorry it should be. I've updated it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use a subquery to get the latest status before a timestamp of a row by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.value
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.value <> (SELECT t2.value
                                 FROM elbat t2
                                 WHERE t2.date < t1.date
                                 ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                                 LIMIT 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=58f55e1e03fdb5baca0630a70d3ccdad)

If you want to include first row (which your sample result does not suggest, but just in case), you can also use the `NULL`-safe comparison.

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.value
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT t1.value <=> (SELECT t2.value
                                      FROM elbat t2
                                      WHERE t2.date < t1.date
                                      ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                                      LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for versions prior to 8.0. Note that, as written, this solution WILL NOT WORK in 8.0+, because of the slightly hacky way that I've arranged it. It could be re-written to work in 8.0+, but because 8.0+ has windowing functions, it would be simpler to use those methods...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(date) date 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT date
                   , value
                   , CASE WHEN @prev = value THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
                   , @prev := value 
                FROM my_table
                   , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
               ORDER 
                  BY date DESC
            ) n 
        GROUP 
           BY i
     ) b 
    ON b.date = a.date;
+---------------------+-------+
| date                | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2019-09-18 11:54:10 |     0 |
| 2019-09-18 11:24:28 |     1 |
| 2019-09-17 12:57:56 |     0 |
| 2019-08-29 15:29:59 |     2 |
| 2019-03-20 11:37:32 |     1 |
| 2019-01-25 11:05:18 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```